# How to add a c++ library on ubuntu

Tags: c++, path, shared-libraries, ubuntu-20.04, .so

I have downloaded a repository from github with a library with git clone
then I typed in terminal "make"
now I have a libmylibrary++.so file in folder mylibrary/src

Now I want to run a c++ file which uses the library but I can't compile it because of this error: "mylibrary.hpp: No such file or directory"

How to add it to PATH? yet I don't understand what exactly I need to add
Whether it is folder "/home/mylibrary" or folder with the .so file

Comment: Do you need to do a `make install` for the library?

Answer (score 2):

Your C++ compiler only knows to search for header files and libraries in standard locations and directories. Just because you downloaded another library in some directory, somewhere, doesn't mean that your C++ compiler will automatically find it.

You will need to change your Makefile and compile your program with the additional compilation options that instruct your C++ compiler to search for header files and libraries in other directories -- typically `-I` and `-L` option.

Additionally, you will probably need to use either `-R` or `-Wl,-rpath` options in order for the compiled code to load the shared libraries from the non-standard locations.

You will find additional information in [the `gcc` manual and documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).